# Change the color of the link in every even div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I've a set of divs which contain some information to be displayed.
How do I change the color of the link text inside every even container?

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.container:nth-child(even){
  background-color: green;
}

.container:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Company website: <a href="abc.html">ABC</a>
  My Profile: <a href="user.html">User1</a>
  <button>Edit</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  Company website: <a href="abc.html">ABC</a>
  My Profile: <a href="user.html">User1</a>
  <button>Edit</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  Company website: <a href="abc.html">ABC</a>
  My Profile: <a href="user.html">User1</a>
  <button>Edit</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  Company website: <a href="abc.html">ABC</a>
  My Profile: <a href="user.html">User1</a>
  <button>Edit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: a {
    color: blue;
}

Comment: give the name to every a tag then used it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add CSS that targets only childs of these divs.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.container:nth-child(even){
  background-color: green;
}

.container:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.container:nth-child(odd) a {
  color: green;
}

.container:nth-child(even) a{
  color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Company website: <a href="abc.html">ABC</a>
  My Profile: <a href="user.html">User1</a>
  <button>Edit</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  Company website: <a href="abc.html">ABC</a>
  My Profile: <a href="user.html">User1</a>
  <button>Edit</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  Company website: <a href="abc.html">ABC</a>
  My Profile: <a href="user.html">User1</a>
  <button>Edit</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  Company website: <a href="abc.html">ABC</a>
  My Profile: <a href="user.html">User1</a>
  <button>Edit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this you mean, where you use `.container:nth-child(even)` to get all even containers, and then add the `a` to target the link `.container:nth-child(even) a { color: red; }`

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.container:nth-child(even){
  background-color: green;
}
.container:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
.container:nth-child(even) a {        /*  added property  */
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Company website: <a href="abc.html">ABC</a>
  My Profile: <a href="user.html">User1</a>
  <button>Edit</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  Company website: <a href="abc.html">ABC</a>
  My Profile: <a href="user.html">User1</a>
  <button>Edit</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  Company website: <a href="abc.html">ABC</a>
  My Profile: <a href="user.html">User1</a>
  <button>Edit</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  Company website: <a href="abc.html">ABC</a>
  My Profile: <a href="user.html">User1</a>
  <button>Edit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: No, not exactly,  the link should be red in every even container.

Comment: @Sunny Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.container:nth-child(even){
  background-color: green;
}

.container:nth-child(even) a{
  background-color: green;
  color: red; <!-- Change the Colour here -->
}

.container:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Company website: <a href="abc.html">ABC</a>
  My Profile: <a href="user.html">User1</a>
  <button>Edit</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  Company website: <a href="abc.html">ABC</a>
  My Profile: <a href="user.html">User1</a>
  <button>Edit</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  Company website: <a href="abc.html">ABC</a>
  My Profile: <a href="user.html">User1</a>
  <button>Edit</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  Company website: <a href="abc.html">ABC</a>
  My Profile: <a href="user.html">User1</a>
  <button>Edit</button>
</div>
```